# Polymer - How to create two main pages in polymer project

Tags: polymer-1.0

I have a polymer project with polymer starter kit. In the project I have the `index.html` the main page of the project.

I need to create an administration page that will be the main page for the administration and I don't find a way to execute another page.

I created the new page `administration.html` and I try to execute the url: http://localhost/administration.html but the routing send me again to the index.html.
I figured out that the problem is with the routing but I don't know exactly how can I fix this.
I will appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Polymer team has just introduced their own approach to the routing problem with the brand new carbon-location and carbon-route elements. You can find a nice intro [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/articles/routing.html) at the main Polymer page. If you want to see how this would work with the starter kit, check out [psk-app](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/blob/psk2/src/psk-app/psk-app.html) at the psk2 branch. The team has just started to do a full rewrite, but you can easily see how routing is handled in Polymer now.

Specifically, look into how they import pages, set the pattern and data attributes in carbon-route and then use the data object exposed by carbon-route in the iron-selector and iron-pages elements with [[params.page]].
Also, Rob Dodson is preparing a [Polycast on carbon-route](https://github.com/Polymer/polycasts/tree/master/ep46-carbon-route/blog) for episode 46, which  will have routing explained in more detail.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Np, happy to help.